# Evaluate $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^4{x}}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> $$f(x) = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^4{x}}}dx$$

I tried this by breaking the denominator as $\sqrt{(\cos^2x)(1+\sin^2x)}$ and then trying to make the integral in forms of $\sec x$ and $\tan x$. But I couldn't succeed.

Can somebody please help me out?

Comment: Are there any bounds?

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt%281-sin%5E4%28x%29%29) was able to evaluate this, although the result is messy.

Comment: If you plug this into the [Integral Calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) and hit "Show steps", you will get a pretty detailed walkthrough.

Comment: @Ty. No there aren't any bounds.

Comment: @VVejalla I didn't know this link, interestingly it gives the *human-ish* solution where other CAS give complicated or Elliptic representation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I=\int \frac{\sec{x}}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2{x}}} \; dx$$
Multiply the top and bottom by $\sec{x}$:
$$I=\int \frac{\sec^2{x}}{\sqrt{\tan^2{x}+\sec^2{x}}} \; dx$$
$$I=\int \frac{\sec^2{x}}{\sqrt{2\tan^2{x}+1}} \; dx$$
Let $u=\tan{x}$:
$$I=\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{2u^2+1}}$$
Let $t=u\sqrt{2}$:
$$I=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$$
Let $t=\tan{w}$:
$$I=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \int \sec{w} \; dw$$
$$I=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \ln {\big | \sec{w}+\tan{w} \big |}+C$$
$$I=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \ln {\big | \sqrt{1+2\tan^2{x}}+\sqrt{2}\tan{x} \big |}+C$$

Comment: A "simpler" form can also be $\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\sinh^{-1}(\sqrt{2}\tan(x))$.

Comment: True.  I try to avoid hyperbolic trig because I usually never know if OP is familiar with it.

Comment: $\sqrt{\cos^2 x} \neq \cos x$.  $\sqrt{\cos^2 x} = |\cos x|$, so you should have $|\sec x|$ in your first integrand's numerator.  You have repeated this omission on the second line when you *actually* multiplied by $|\sec x| / |\sec x|$ but described it differently.

Answer (score -1):

Taking $t = \tan \frac{x}{2}$ and having $\sin x = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ we come to irrational function.